How can an overly large font display within figures be fixed to have a normal size?
After installing Matlab on my new work pc, fonts within figures (axes, labels, texts) appear much larger in comparison to that of the editor and task bars, even if the font size value properties have not changed from their default ones. I would like to understand how this happened and how I can get it "back to normal" so that I can see figures rendered similarly on different machines. I have done some research to try and understand where this could originate from, but I'm at a loss. Here are some facts:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Matlab version 2024a (an install of 2023b showed the same issue)
The scale of monitor display settings is set at 100%
The same issue occurs if I run matlab in -nosoftwareopengl and -softwareopengl.
Drivers of the graphics card seem to be installed correctly

I'm happy to provide additional information on request, but at the moment I have no clue what could help.

